# How to call Global.asax value in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

This is my VB code for global.asax

```
<%@ Application Language="VB">
<script runat="server">

Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs on application startup
    Application("CS") = "server=myServer; user id=myUser; password=MyPaas; database=myData; pooling=true"
End Sub

Sub Application_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs on application shutdown
    Application("CS") = ""

End Sub

Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
End Sub

Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when a new session is started
End Sub

Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when a session ends.
    ' Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    ' is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer
    ' or SQLServer, the event is not raised.
End Sub

</script>
```

I call this value in VB like this: 
    `Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(Application("CS"))`

How to do this call in C# ASP.NET?

Comment: Simply like this:  `SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(Application["CS"]);`.  Alternatively you could put it in a `using` block.

Comment: I am getting this error now on my default.aspx page Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Application.get' 
and Application is not accessible In which assembly for Application. –

Comment: Where are you making the call?  In the Page_Load event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent C# code would be:

```
SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(Application["CS"]);
```

Note the [] around "CS" instead of the ().

Alternatively, you could do it in a using block:

```
using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(Application["CS"]))
{

    // Do your data access here
}
```

The using block ensures that dispose is called (even if an exception is encountered).  For more information on the using statement, see [using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Though I wonder - why are you using C# with a Global.asax file that's written in VB.NET?

Comment: I am getting this error now on my default.aspx 

page Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Application.get'

Comment: and Application is not accessible In which assembly for Application.

Comment: And I am not using VB code with my C# actually I know code in VB but now I need to generate C# website there I need how to use that in  C#.

Comment: Try `Global.Application["CS"]` instead of `Application["CS"]` and see if that works - if it does I'll update my answer.